# Why am I getting this error while running Docker Container?

Tags: dockerfile, docker-desktop, semantic-segmentation

[Docker Desktop ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGWWi.png) I am following this repository to setup the environment for radar semantic segmentation.
https://github.com/valeoai/MVRSS/

I am using Docker to install all the dependencies. Particularly at step 2, when it comes to running a container, i am facing the following error (screenshot of Docker Desktop also attached).

Command:

docker run -d --ipc=host -it -v /home/shahidnawaz/datasets:/home/datasets_local -v /home/shahidnawaz/logs:/home/logs --name mvrss --gpus all mvrss:Dockerfile sleep infinity

Error:

docker: Error response from daemon: failed to create task for container: failed to create shim task: OCI runtime create failed: runc create failed: unable to start container process: error during container init: error running hook #0: error running hook: exit status 1, stdout: , stderr: Auto-detected mode as 'legacy'
nvidia-container-cli: initialization error: load library failed: libnvidia-ml.so.1: cannot open shared object file: no such file or directory: unknown.

I am new to using these tools, I have already tried different solutions available online. Any help regarding solution would be much appreciated.
Thanks.